# lubuntu after install not booting up?

Tags: lubuntu, customization, grub-efi, custom-installer

After running a custom made LUbuntu automatic install nothing boots up.
The automation used `d-i commands` and a `custom.seed` file

My machine is a UEFI type, but the funny thing is if I try installation from ubiquity via live boot everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: My suspicion is that your custom configuration is not installing the correct boot loader, but that's just a guess. You need to install an EFI-mode boot loader (typically `grub-efi`), and you may need to configure it, too. That said, I'm not familiar enough with your installation method to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @RodSmith thank you for the thought i am going to look into it.